# Driver for Bresser MikroOcular camera

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I have recently installed Xubuntu 16.04.

I have a camera for a microscope Bresser - MikroOcular - with driver meant for Windows.
I had like to know if it is possible to find a driver for this type a camera under Xubuntu.
If somebody has the answer...

UPDATE: dmesg output:

```
[ 6214.309512] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 6221.627201] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 6221.793737] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=3822
[ 6221.793743] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 6221.793746] usb 1-1: Product: MikrOkularHD
[ 6221.797038] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device MikrOkularHD (058f:3822)
[ 6221.801171] uvcvideo 1-1:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[ 6221.801178] uvcvideo 1-1:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 6 was not initialized!
[ 6221.801182] uvcvideo 1-1:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[ 6221.801534] input: MikrOkularHD: MikrOkularHD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input34
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how it presents itself to Windows?  As a camera?  as a webcam?  As a scanner?

Comment: Seems these devices are USB.  It should be listed as `lsusb`.  First instinct would be to equate it as a webcam.  Try to see whether the program "Cheese" finds it.  Yes, I know cheesy suggestion.

Comment: 1. Disconnect the camera. 2. Execute the `lastdmesg="$(dmesg  | tail -n 1| egrep -o '\[[ .0-9]+\]')"` command (to store the last timestamp in `lastdmesg`). 3. Connect the camera and wait several seconds. 4. Execute the `dmesg | fgrep  -A65535 "$lastdmesg"` command. 5. Copy that output, Edit your post and add that data.

Comment: You could try to install the Windows software in Ubuntu under Wine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I will check each one and will come back with the outcome !

Comment: @tschip It's 2018 and you still didn't. I was considering purchasing this camera, but want to know if it's usable on Linux as I don't want to be locked into manufacturer software.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the proper driver, but at least [AstroDMx Capture](https://www.linux-astro-imaging.uk/) works with this camera in my Xubuntu 16.04.7.

The latest version, however, needs some newer libraries, but [older version](https://www.linux-astro-imaging.uk/linux/astronomy/linux-downloads-old) (0.68.1) worked out-of-box perfectly.

Comment: worked out of the box on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

VLC shows the video capture device output without any problem, no need to load anything else. Tested with VLC version 3.0.9.2 in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. The camera is MikrOkular HD, Art. No. 5913720, and came with Bresser Biolux NV microscope.

Comment: That it works now doesn't mean it worked back then when the question was posted. A lot changed since 16.04.